# add a button to grid view in yii2

Tags: php, web, yii2, php-5.3

i'm a new yii2 developer !
i made a GridView and the code is shown below :

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn'],
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'id',
            'countryCode',
            'countryName',
            'currencyCode',
        ],
    ]); ?>
    <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

a screenshot of output :
[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BI6fy.png)

now i want to have a column contain some button and that button for example open a page or somthing else !
my problem is how can i create that column ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can also add the button (or as many as you like) to the existing action column like this

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    ::
    ::
    'columns' => [
        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'template' => '{view} {update} {delete} {myButton}',  // the default buttons + your custom button
            'buttons' => [
                'myButton' => function($url, $model, $key) {     // render your custom button
                    return Html::a(..);
                }
            ]
        ]
        ::
        ::
        'currencyCode'
    ]   
]); ?>
```

Comment: Hello. Where I can find some documentation about this ?

Comment: @defro Hope this wil help as a starting point https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-grid-actioncolumn

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn'],
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'id',
        'countryCode',
        'countryName',
        'currencyCode',
        [
            'label' => 'My Label',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => Html::a('Click me', ['site/index'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success btn-xs', 'data-pjax' => 0])
        ]
    ],
]); ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
[
            'header' => 'Button',
            'content' => function($model) {
                return Html::a(..);
            }           
],
```

[More Info](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-column.html#$content-detail)

Comment: thanks !! i write this code now : `'countryCode',
            'countryName',
            'currencyCode',
            [
                'header' => 'Button',
                'content' => function($model) {
                    return Html::a($text='Test',$url='https://www.google.com');
                    }
            ], ` now i have antother problem , how can i make the text of this button one thing from database ? i mean how can i have for example a countryname column that actually be a button not just text ? @insaneSkull

Comment: Use [contentOptions](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-column.html#$contentOptions-detail) and [headerOptions](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-column.html#$headerOptions-detail). add any html style you want.

Comment: sorry but i don't understand ! i understand the $key is the ID but how can i acsses the text of my database ?

Comment: @sass. You mean database value? it's in `$model` variable.

Comment: yes database . i mean for example the button or link tag is in the line 6 then the text of the a tag be the one of the database values ! i write this code but it's not right :`'content' => function($model ,$key,$index, $column) {
                        return Html::a($text=$model,$url='google.com');
                    }`

Comment: @sass. really don't get it.  show normal html anchor you want, i will convert in yii2 anchor.

Comment: for example i have this column :  `'countryCode'`, . i want have a column like this : `[
                'header' => 'edit City',
                'content' => function($model,$key,$index, $column) {
                    return Html::button('>',$options = ['onclick'=>'editshow('.$key.')','style' => ['border'=>'solid 2px blue']]);
                }
            ],` but i don't want the text be '>' . i want the text be the countryCode of that row . thanks :) !

Comment: @sass. Write `$model->countryCode`

Comment: @sass. `Html::a($model->countryCode, $url, ['onclick'=>'editshow('.$key.')','style' => ['border'=>'solid 2px blue'])`

Comment: @sass. Mark as helpful, so it can be useful for others.

Comment: sorry for bothering you but i forgot to ask something . now i create my own cusom column but if i want give some option to a column that contain database column for example `'countryCode',
        'countryName',
        'currencyCode',` what shold i do ? i mean for example give this column a onclick attribute or ... . i actually want create something like KARTIK GRIDVIEW !!!!

Comment: Use `['attribute' => 'column_name', 'value' => function($model) { return 'anything';}]`