# How to send POST for only one row in gridview

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I'am creating table where customers can sort records as they wish. How to POST only single row from entire table?

I already tried to wrap whole GridView table into form, result is that when I submit, whole table gets POST'ed, not the specific record.

Here is a GridView:

```
        <?=Html::beginForm(['list-profile/resort'], 'post', ['class' => 'form-inline', 'name' => 'resort-channel-list']);?>
        <?=GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'filterModel' => $searchModel,
            'pager' => [
                'firstPageLabel' => Yii::t('app', 'First'),
                'lastPageLabel' => Yii::t('app', 'Last'),
            ],
            'columns' => [
                [
                    'label'=>'#',
                    'attribute' => 'channel.sort',
                    'value' => 'channel.sort',
                ],
                [
                    'label'=>'Sort No.',
                    'attribute'=>'no',
                    'format' => 'raw',
                    'value'=> function ($data) {
                        return Html::textInput("sort",$data->no,array("style"=>"width:40px;"));
                    },
                ],
                [
                    'label'=>'Action',
                    'attribute'=>'no',
                    'format' => 'raw',
                    'value'=> function ($data) {
                        return Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Save'), ['class' => 'btn btn-success']);
                    },
                ],
                [
                    'attribute' => 'channel.name',
                    'format' => 'raw',
                    'value' => function ($data) {
                        return Html::a($data->getChannelName($data->channel_id), ['update', 'id' => $data->id, 'name' => Yii::$app->request->get('name')], ['data-pjax' => 0]);
                    },
                ],
                 'create_time',
                 'update_time',
                ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                    'template' => '{remove} | {save}',
                    'buttons' => [
                        'remove' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
                            return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger"></span>', ['list-profile/index', 'rem_id' => $model->id, 'name' => Yii::$app->request->get('name')], ['title' => Yii::t('app', 'Remove from profile'),
                             ]
                            );
                        },
                    ],
                    'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'min-width: 80px;text-align: center;'],
                ],
            ]
        ]);?>
        <?=Html::endForm();?>
```

Here is image how table looks like:

[Picture of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1HE9.png)

Comment: you should wrap each row in from instead of whole table.

Comment: Yes, in plain PHP I would do that, but how to do that in Yii2 GridView?

Comment: When you click the save button ( if i understand) you can make an ajax call to a specific action of your controller, where you can save your data

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly. My skills with Yii2 is to low for such task without example. Could you point me to example or documentation entry how to do that?

Comment: In this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39716563/add-a-button-to-grid-view-in-yii2) you can find how to add a custom button. After that you have to register a js file for this view where you can make your AJAX request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete `beginForm`. And do the following:

**1**- change it:

```
return Html::textInput("sort",$data->no,array("style"=>"width:40px;"));
```

**to:**

```
return Html::textInput($data->no,$data->no,array("style"=>"width:40px;"));
```

**2**- change it:

```
return Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Save'), ['class' => 'btn btn-success']);
```

**to:**

```
return Html::a('list-profile/resort', 'send', ['class' => 'btn btn-success','id' => $data->no,]);
```

Then add the code:

```
<?php
$script = <<< JS
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var key =$(this).attr('no');
    var dat = $('input[name='+key+']').val();
    $.post("list-profile/resort",
    {
      'textinput' : dat
    },
    function(data,status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "Status: " + status);
    });
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

---

**If you want to do through Ajax:**

```
 $.ajax({
url: 'list-profile/resort',
 type: 'POST',
data: {'textinput' : dat },
 success:function(result){
 alert(dat)
 },
 error: function(){
 alert('Error!')
 }
 });
```

---

**If you want to start with beginForm? (do not delete `beginForm` and `submitButton`)**

```
return Html::textInput($data->no,$data->no,array("style"=>"width:40px;"));

return Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Save'), ['class' => 'btn btn-success','id' => $data->no]);
```

```
$('form').find(':submit').on('click', function(event) {
    // Prevent default anchor click behavior
    event.preventDefault();

    var key =$(this).attr('no');
    var dat = $('input[name='+key+']').val();
        $.post("list-profile/resort",
        {
          'textinput' : dat
        },
        function(data,status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "Status: " + status);
        });
});
```

**For URL, you can also use the following code in JS:**

```
 var url= $(this).attr('href');
```

Comment: Nice! I'am getting closer... When I insert your suggestion I receiving empty array (POST). Could you a bit adapt your example to my code?

Answer (score 2):

There is a `data-key` attribute that associates the rows with the record in the 
`Gridview` you can use it to target that specific row and collect the inputs.

Then why are you assigning a button inside a `Data` column you should place it inside the `Action` column instead which is for this purpose.

### Things to Do

- You should first change the `Html::submitButton()` to a normal button and add a class `submit` and a `data-key` attribute and move it to the `Action` column.

  ```
  return Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Save'), ['class' => 'btn btn-success']);
  ```

  to

  ```
  return Html::button(Yii::t('app', 'Save'), ['class' => 'btn btn-success submit' , 'data-key' => $key]);
  ```
- Assign an id to your `GridView` i am using `mygrid`.
- Move the new button we created to the action column from the data column, your code

  will look like below

  ```
  [
      'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
      'template' => '{remove} | {save} {submitRow}',
      'buttons' => [
          'submitRow' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
              return Html::button('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-success submit', 'data-key' => $key]);
          },
          'remove' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
              return Html::a(
                  '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger"></span>',
                  ['list-profile/index', 'rem_id' => $model->id, 'name' => Yii::$app->request->get('name')],
                  [
                      'title' => Yii::t('app', 'Remove from profile'),
                  ]
              );
          },
      ],
      'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'min-width: 80px;text-align: center;'],
  ],
  ```
- Add the following script on the top of your view

  ```
  $js = <<<JS
  $('.submit').click(function(){

      //get the row key from target button
      var rowNum=$(this).data('key');

      var data={};

      //add the id to the collection for update
      data["id"]=rowNum;

      //collect the inputs data from the td inside the row

      $('#mygrid table').find('[data-key="'+rowNum+'"]').find('td').each(function(){
          $(this).find('input').each(function(){
              data[$(this).attr('name')]=$(this).val();
          });
      });

      //send an ajax call
      $.ajax({
          url:'list-profile/resort',
          method:'post',
          data:data,
          success:function(response){
              alert(response);
          },
          error: function (XHR, status, error) {
              alert("Oops! Status " + status + " returned with error "+error);
          }
      });
  });
  JS;

  $this->registerJs($js, \yii\web\View::POS_END);
  ?>
  ```

Once you do the above your data will be under the `post` array and you can get it like

```
Yii::$app->request->post('sort')
```